# .net EntityFramework where via many to many link and nested table joins

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-mapping

SQL queries such as the one below but using entity framework?

```
SELECT     Software.Vendor, Software.Version, 
Rollout.ID, Software.Name, Rollout.Name 

FROM         org_User INNER JOIN
                      SoftwareUser ON org_User.ID = SoftwareUser.FK_org_User_ID INNER JOIN
                      Software ON Software.ID = SoftwareUser.FK_Software_ID INNER JOIN
                      AssetAssignee ON org_User.ID = AssetAssignee.FK_org_User_ID INNER JOIN
                      Rollout ON AssetAssignee.FK_Rollout_ID = Rollout.ID INNER JOIN
                      Location ON AssetAssignee.FK_Location_ID = Location.ID
WHERE     (Rollout.ID = 44) AND (Location.ID = 2)
GROUP BY Software.Vendor, Software.Version, 
Rollout.ID, Software.Name, Rollout.Name
```

DB Schema (note the many to many table 'SoftwareUser')
[image: DB schema]

Entity Framework edmx model (many to many table 'SoftwareUser' is not displayed as the designer acknowledges its just a pure many to many link table and illustrates this with a join line with an asterisk at either end)

[image]

I attempted to use the PredicateBuilder utility class, but the way I did it below became apparent as being quite wrong in that I could not make it build out the query in the way I'm using it. So no joy there.

```
 internal static List<Software> GetApplications(
        string UserID,
        string Surname,
        string Forname,
        int? TeamID,
        int? LocationID,
        int? RolloutID,
        string EmployeeID)
    {
        {
            var predicate = GetApplicationsPredicate(UserID, Surname, Forname, TeamID, LocationID, RolloutID, EmployeeID);

            using (ITAMEFContext db = new ITAMEFContext(ConnectionStrings.ITAM_ConnectionString_EF))
            {
                db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                return db.Softwares.Where(predicate).ToList();

            }
        }
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Software, bool>> GetApplicationsPredicate(
        string UserID,
        string Surname,
        string Forname,
        int? TeamID,
        int? LocationID,
        int? RolloutID,
        string EmployeeID)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Software>();

        bool nothingSelected = (
            TeamID == null
            && LocationID == null
            && RolloutID == null
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Forname)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeID)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID)
            );

        if (nothingSelected)
        {
            // we need to negate the first true predicate of we don't have any other predicates.
            predicate = predicate.And(u => !(nothingSelected));
            return predicate;
        }

        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID))
        //    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Select(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.org_User.DomainUserID.Contains(UserID))) != null);

        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname))
        //    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.org_User.Surname.Contains(Surname))));

        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Forname))
        //    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.org_User.Forename.Contains(Forname)))); ;

        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeID))
        //    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.org_User.EmployeeID.Contains(EmployeeID))));

        if (LocationID.HasValue)
            predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.Location.ID == LocationID.Value)));

        //if (TeamID.HasValue)
        //    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.org_User.org_Team.ID == TeamID.Value)));

        if (RolloutID.HasValue)
            predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.Rollout.ID == RolloutID)));

        //if (RolloutID.HasValue)
        //    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.org_User.Any(u => u.AssetAssignees.Any(aa => aa.Rollout.ID == RolloutID)));

        return predicate;
    }
```

But this only resulted in the following inappropriate SQL being generated.

```
    SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FK_ApptrackerID] AS [FK_ApptrackerID], 
[Extent1].[FK_SoftwareType_ID] AS [FK_SoftwareType_ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Vendor] AS [Vendor], 
[Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
[Extent1].[Ready] AS [Ready]
FROM [dbo].[Software] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent2].[FK_org_User_ID] AS [FK_org_User_ID]
        FROM [dbo].[SoftwareUser] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[FK_Software_ID]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AssetAssignee] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE ([Project1].[FK_org_User_ID] = [Extent3].[FK_org_User_ID]) AND ([Extent3].[FK_Location_ID] = 2)
    )
)) 

AND 

( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent4].[FK_org_User_ID] AS [FK_org_User_ID]
        FROM [dbo].[SoftwareUser] AS [Extent4]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent4].[FK_Software_ID]
    )  AS [Project4]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[AssetAssignee] AS [Extent5]
        WHERE ([Project4].[FK_org_User_ID] = [Extent5].[FK_org_User_ID]) AND ([Extent5].[FK_Rollout_ID] = 44)
    )
))
```

please help :'(

**EF dll version 4.4.0.0 |
Method - database first |
.net 4.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on the following query syntax in the end which appears to bring back the correct results.

```
internal static List<Software> GetApplications(
            string UserID,
            string Surname,
            string Forname,
            int? TeamID,
            int? LocationID,
            int? RolloutID,
            string EmployeeID)
        {
            {

                using (ITAMEFContext db = new ITAMEFContext(ConnectionStrings.ITAM_ConnectionString_EF))
                {
                    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

                    return (from ou in db.org_User
                           from sw in ou.Softwares
                           from aa in ou.AssetAssignees
                           where aa.org_User.DomainUserID.Contains(UserID)
                           &&
                           (!TeamID.HasValue || aa.org_User.org_Team.ID == TeamID)
                           &&
                           (!LocationID.HasValue || aa.org_User.Location.ID == LocationID.Value)
                           &&
                           (!RolloutID.HasValue || aa.Rollout.ID == RolloutID)
                           &&
                           aa.org_User.Surname.Contains(Surname)
                           &&
                           aa.org_User.Forename.Contains(Forname)
                           &&
                           aa.org_User.EmployeeID.Contains(EmployeeID)
                           group sw by sw.ID into swG

                           select swG).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are queries that are impossible to write in EF, but the query you show is really not that hard, esp. not when you use query syntax and exploit the power of navigation properties:

```
from ou in db.org_User
from sw in ou.Softwares
from aa in ou.AssetAssignees
select new { sw.Vendor, sw.Version, aa.Rollout.ID, aa.Rollout.Name }
```

You don't need the `group by` because you select exactly the same fields as the ones you group by. Neither do you need access the junction table because EF does the joining for you.

If you want to apply the predicates you can start the statement by

```
from ou in db.org_User.Where(predicate)
```

Comment: 'from aa in sw.AssetAssignees' did not work as Softwares does not link to AssetAssignee. My assumption of the way predicates work was incorrect as each added condition attempted to drill down to a table though the navigation properties within the actual add predicate of each of the add predicates I wrote. But this was incorrect usage. You pointed me in the right direction however ;) See resolution below.

Comment: `sw.AssetAssignees` was a typo.

Comment: It was interesting to note that the group by was needed in the end. I believe this is due to the nature of the entity framework in that since the SQL needed it to return the correct results I had to include it.